# How to add a caption next to figure elegantly (with control parameters)?

Tags: floats, minipage

I need to have a figure function that place the caption next to it.

The figure ratio should be controlled with "x*textwidth" and the caption ratio is "y*textwidth". So far so good!

This function should control the distances of the figure from the red vertical borders with parameter "1" and "2", left and right side respectively.

Similarly, parameters "3" and "4" controls the distances of caption from the green vertical borders.

[image]

I have tried hard could not achieve. If any one helps me to create this template/preamble, I appreciate a lot.

This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,center},capbesidewidth=4cm,floatrowsep=quad}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz.}\label{Fig:1}}
{\centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{chapter-1/Figures/1.png}} 
\end{figure}
```

It creates something like this! but it is based on trial & error too much.

[image]

EDIT/UPDATE:

If I follow the answer provided by @leandriis it creates something like this:

I want to be able to control left margin for the figure and the right for the caption. How can I do that?

[image]

SOLUTION:

Werner's solution worked well! Please check my comment at there if you are using \usepackage{multicol}.

Comment: Aside from nomenclature regarding figures and images, one could easily set this up with a couple of minipages.  Not sure why you need 4 arguments instead of just 2.  The gaps can be calculated or automated using \hfill.

Comment: Why does the image you should not resemble what you're after?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have tried to use 'minipages', but I have failed to move the image and the caption to the center. What I mean the image does not follow the line 1 but starts indented and the caption does not go till the line 4, but it is also indented with respect to right margin. Moreover, I also want to fine tune the gap between image and its caption. Maybe you can help me by providing a code!

Comment: @Werner it is a good question, maybe it looks like what I am after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a key-valued approach to what you're after. Keys you can set include

- `left` - the left margin/gap (default = `0pt`)
- `right` - the right margin/gap (default = `0pt`)
- `figcapsep` - the horizontal gap between the figure/image and the caption (default = `\tabcolsep`)
- `figwidth` - the width of the figure/image (calculated if not specified)
- `capwidth` - the width of the caption (calculated if not specified)
- `figlabel` - the `\label` that should be used with `\caption`
- `captiontoc` - the optional argument using in `\caption[<ToC>]{<text>}`.

The entire construction fits within `\linewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{xkeyval,float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey{iac}{left}[0pt]{}% \cmdKV@iac@left
\define@cmdkey{iac}{right}[0pt]{}% \cmdKV@iac@right
\define@cmdkey{iac}{figcapsep}[\tabcolsep]{}% \cmdKV@iac@figcapsep
\define@cmdkey{iac}{figwidth}[\relax]{}% \cmdKV@iac@figwidth
\define@cmdkey{iac}{capwidth}[\relax]{}% \cmdKV@iac@capwidth
\define@cmdkey{iac}{figlabel}[\relax]{}% \cmdKV@iac@figlabel
\define@cmdkey{iac}{captiontoc}[\relax]{}% \cmdKV@iac@captiontoc

\newcommand{\imageandcaption}[3][]{%
  \setkeys{iac}{
    left,right,figcapsep,figwidth,capwidth,figlabel,captiontoc,% Set default keys
    #1% Set updated keys
  }%
  \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@iac@figwidth\relax% No figure width supplied
    \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@iac@capwidth\relax% No caption width supplied
      \def\cmdKV@iac@figwidth{.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\cmdKV@iac@left-\cmdKV@iac@right-\cmdKV@iac@figcapsep}%
      \def\cmdKV@iac@capwidth{\cmdKV@iac@figwidth}%
    \else% Caption width provided
      \def\cmdKV@iac@figwidth{\dimexpr\linewidth-\cmdKV@iac@left-\cmdKV@iac@right-\cmdKV@iac@figcapsep-\cmdKV@iac@capwidth}%
    \fi
  \else% Figure width supplied
    \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@iac@capwidth\relax% No caption width supplied
      \def\cmdKV@iac@capwidth{\dimexpr\linewidth-\cmdKV@iac@left-\cmdKV@iac@right-\cmdKV@iac@figcapsep-\cmdKV@iac@figwidth}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \hspace*{\cmdKV@iac@left}% Indent from left margin
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=\cmdKV@iac@figwidth]{#2}% Insert image
  \hspace*{\cmdKV@iac@figcapsep}% Space between image and caption
  \begin{minipage}{\cmdKV@iac@capwidth}
    \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@iac@captiontoc\relax
      \caption{#3}% \caption without ToC entry
    \else
      \caption[\cmdKV@iac@captiontoc]{#3}% \caption with ToC entry
    \fi
    \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@iac@figlabel\relax\else
      \label{\cmdKV@iac@figlabel}%
    \fi
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace*{\cmdKV@iac@right}% Space on right of construction
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See Figure~\ref{fig:figure1}.\sloppy

\begin{figure}[H]
  \imageandcaption[
    left=10pt,
    figwidth=.3\linewidth,
    capwidth=.6\linewidth,
    figlabel=fig:figure1%
  ]
  {example-image-a}{This is a caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[H]
  \raggedleft
  \imageandcaption[
    right=10pt,
    figwidth=.6\linewidth,
    capwidth=.3\linewidth,
    figlabel=fig:figure2]
  {example-image-b}{\lipsum[2]}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[H]
  \imageandcaption
    {example-image-c}{\lipsum[2]}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Werner! The code works very well and it was what I was looking for. One warning for everyone may face with a similar situation. I was using \usepackage{multicol} before \usepackage{xkeyval,float} and 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} in the preamble. However, it breaks the functionality. I moved \usepackage{multicol} after the others.Then the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

With the following custom command `\setmyimagewidth` you can set the width of the current image. If you then use `width=\myimagewidth` as an option to the `\includegraphics` command and `capbesidewidth=\mycaptionwidth` as an option to `\thisfloatsetup`, the width of the image an caption will adapt to the overall textwidth automatically aligning the left border of the image with the left margin and the right border of the caption with the right margin:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\myimagewidth}
\newlength{\mycaptionwidth}
\setlength{\mycaptionwidth}{\textwidth-\myimagewidth-10pt}

\newcommand{\setmyimagewidth}[1]{\setlength{\myimagewidth}{#1}
\setlength{\mycaptionwidth}{\textwidth-\myimagewidth-10pt}}
\begin{document}
%\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!h]
\setmyimagewidth{0.55\textwidth}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,center},capbesidewidth=\mycaptionwidth,floatrowsep=quad}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz. xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz. xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz. xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz.xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz.xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz.}\label{Fig:1}}
{\centering\includegraphics[width=\myimagewidth]{example-image}} 
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[!h]
\setmyimagewidth{0.15\textwidth}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,center},capbesidewidth=\mycaptionwidth,floatrowsep=quad}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz. xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz. xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz. xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz.xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz.xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz.}\label{Fig:1}}
{\centering\includegraphics[width=\myimagewidth]{example-image}} 
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[!h]
\setmyimagewidth{0.3\textwidth}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,center},capbesidewidth=\mycaptionwidth,floatrowsep=quad}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz. xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz. xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz. xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz.xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz.xyzxyz xyz xyz xyz xyz.}\label{Fig:1}}
{\centering\includegraphics[width=\myimagewidth]{example-image}} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @leandriis, I have tried your solution, but I could not achieve what I wanted. I have modified the entry with your solution and indicated with arrows what I want more. Do you know how can I achieve that? Thank you!